# "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" error when trying to bind to a socket

Tags: python, sockets, udp, broadcasting

```
broadcaster = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
broadcaster.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
broadcaster.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

def send_broadcast_thread():
    msg = "test"
    while True:
        # TODO: write logic for sending broadcasts.
        broadcaster.sendto(msg.encode(), ('255.255.255.255', get_broadcast_port()))
        print(msg.encode())
        time.sleep(1)

def receive_broadcast_thread():
    broadcaster.bind(('', get_broadcast_port()))
    while True:
        data, (ip, port) = broadcaster.recvfrom(4096)
        print(f"RECV: {data} FROM: T{ip}:{port}")
```

I get this error when I try to run this code. I call each function of them in a separate daemon thread.

```
line 88, in receive_broadcast_thread
    broadcaster.bind(('', get_broadcast_port())) OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you're providing an invalid hostname (empty string) on the second line of your `receive_broadcast_thread()` function.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, you can `bind` a socket at most once.  For example, the Linux [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) say:

> `EINVAL` The socket is already bound to an address.

the `EINVAL` error number is defined as:

```c
#define EINVAL          22      /* Invalid argument */
```

which seems to match up with what you're getting.

To fix your problem, I'd try moving the `bind` out of `receive_broadcast_thread` to just after where you set all the socket options

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This does solve the error but when I try running the code from two terminals at once it prints the same port number in both of them ( in the receive_broadcast function) But it should print two port numbers because they should act as two separate devices, right?

Comment: that would depend on what `get_broadcast_port` is doing.  you're setting `SO_REUSEADDR` so you're allowing multiple programs to be bound to that UDP port.  maybe post another question that includes the relevant details?